# Delete and Update Rows with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, input

I do not have access to my database and cannot use a SQL function so I am trying to figure out a way to delete an array from a list when the user deletes it. Here is my code.

```
<table id="links" width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>Display</b></td>
        <td><b>Link *</b></td>

                    <?php

        if ( isset($_POST['links']) ) {

            $displays = $_POST['displays'];
            $links = $_POST['links'];
            $domain = $_POST['domain'];
            $options = get_option("autodomain_links") or array();

            foreach($links as $i => $link) {
                if ( empty($displays[$i]) )
                    $displays[$i] = "";
                if (!empty($links[$i]))
                {
                    $autodomain = array('displays' => $displays[$i], 'links' => $links[$i], 'domain' => $domain);
                    $options[] = $autodomain;
                }
            }

            //$dump = array();
            update_option("autodomain_links",  $options);

        }

        $options = get_option("autodomain_links");

        if ($options) {

            foreach($options as $i => $option) {
                    echo '<tr id="id_'.$i.'">';
                    echo '<td><input type="button" class="delete" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow(links)"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $option['displays'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $option['links'] . ' ' . $option['domain'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }



        }   
        ?>
```

This is the delete row javascript I am currently using:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }

        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

This is the code which the table above receives data from... this is the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="links">
<!-- start -->
Domain: <input type="text" id="set-domain" value=".syr.edu" name="domain"/> <br><br>
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;Display</b></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;Link *</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="displays[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="links[]"></td>
        <td><span class="domain">.syr.edu</span><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"/>
        <td><input type="text" name="displays[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="links[]"></td>
        <td><span class="domain">.syr.edu</span><br></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <br>
        <input type="button" name="addlink" value="+" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"/>
        <input type="submit" name="savelink" value="Add New Link" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the database and you can't run sql queries, how are you getting the data in the first place?

Comment: ... and what's to prevent the deleted row(s) from showing up again once the page is refreshed?

Comment: I am using wordpress database and hoped that I could use a update function vs going through the wordpress database

Comment: I wanted to create some type of if statement.. if the delete button is clicked remove and update.

Comment: Wordpress offers its own DB abstraction library: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb